# Alternative to google maps places autocomplete

Tags: flutter

is there any alternative to google to implement a places autocomplete in flutter?
I am developing an application that needs the geolocation of places (I don't need to show the map) and use their coordinates

Comment: This smells a bit like a software recommendation request, which are off-topic here. See #3 of [help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Open Routes API's asi an alternative solution.

https://openrouteservice.org/dev/#/api-docs

Check that service as a reference... There is an option called "Directions" that can help what you are looking for...